# Add a field value to text box

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access Table named `Count`. It has one field named `Anz` and it has only 1 record. I want to Show this record in a TextBox on a form named `overview`. So in the design mode of the form inside the TextBox I use the code

```
[Count]![Anz]
```

but it Returns me `#Name?` error when I Switch back to form mode. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use in Control Source of your unbound text box `=Dlookup("[Anz]","[Count]")`

Also you can bound your form to `Count` table and use for text box control source `Anz`